# simplexml_load_file problems

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following code to read in an XML file:

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file('http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=334704593230758'); 
$item = $xml2->channel->item;
```

I am getting the following back in my source code:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&amp;id=334704593230758:11: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in <b>/home/content/49/8644249/html/test/_inc/footer.php</b> on line <b>110</b><br />
```

it continues on  like that for 10 more lines.  Is there a problem with the xml code?

Comment: A quick Google (which you could have done) reveals that this means there is an unencoded ampersand in the file (all stray `&` should be `&amp;`). Looks like facebook doesn't output properly `html_entities()`'d RSS feeds.

Comment: Ooooh somebody at FB's gonna get an ass kicking for that... Although I'm inspecting the XML currently returned by that URL and there is no such problem with it - and there are several correctly encoded entities in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, slightly weirdly since this is an RSS feed and not designed to be directly human-readable, the answer to this is that you have to include a `User-Agent:` header in your request.

When I load the URL in Chrome a get valid XML document, when I run you code I get the same errors you do. Upon closer inspection I find that when I run your code I actually get a minimal HTML document back, not the desired XML - in order to get the right result you have to pass a valid user agent string, which means you can't use `simplexml_load_file()` because it doesn't support stream contexts.

This code works for me:

```
// User-Agent string from Chrome. I haven't tested anything else so I don't know
// what is actually required, but this works.
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http'=>array(
    'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'
   )
));

// Get data as a string
$xml2 = file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=334704593230758', FALSE, $context);

// Convert string to a SimpleXML object
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);

$item = $xml2->channel->item;
```