# PHP - Anyway of setting a referrer when using simplexml_load_file to load an XML file from a URL?

Tags: php, xml, header, vimeo, referrer

Vimeo.com allows restricing video embedding to specifics domains. However when embedding a video I have a script that queries Vimeo for details on the video. This request is made via PHP's simplexml_load_file() function, the target url is the Vimeo video URL. Since the referrer field is blank however Vimeo does not allow access to the video and the script cannot get any video details.

Unfortunately Vimeo does not allow whitelisting IP addresses, the only way around this privacy setting is to set a referrer to make it look like the request is coming from a browser trying to watch the video on my site.

I need to know how I can set a referrer- I'm not seeing any way- hoping there is something I missed.

The specific line is:

```
  $sxml = simplexml_load_file($target_url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can set all headers you want to including the *referrer* for [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) by setting the header field in the so called *stream context* for that function.

This is done via [`libxml_set_streams_context`](http://php.net/libxml_set_streams_context).

Code example (the pinback does not work, it just shows that loading XML works and how to set headers):

```
$options = [
    "http" => [
        "header"        => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                           "Referer: http://www.example.com\r\n",
        "ignore_errors" => true,
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$url = "http://vimeo.com/_pingback";

$sxl = simplexml_load_file($url);
$sxl->asXML("php://output");
```

Releated question:

- [simplexml_load_file problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11620932/367456) - An answer there shows how to use stream contexts with `file_get_contents` then passing the HTTP response body to `simplexml_load_string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');
$xml = curl_exec($ch);

$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Comment: I appreciate this but I cannot rely on cURL always being available. For this reason I will be accepting the other answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is specifically about setting the referrer, but there are some issues with your original idea.

The way you are accessing the video metadata is not supported by Vimeo, and will break in the future without any advanced warning.

The [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api) is the only supported way to retrieve video metadata.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, unfortunately the code package I am working with is already old and unsupported. WIll just have to hope it holds out long enough.